# Group by on custom table not working

Tags: sql, database, informix

I have below query:

```
SELECT bt.app_id, MAX(bt.id) as user_id
FROM (SELECT bt.*
  FROM user bt
  WHERE bt.app_id IN (SELECT bs.id
                                FROM
                                  (SELECT max(id) as id, app_id, count(id) AS count
                                   FROM user_turn bt
                                   WHERE  bt.state = 'pending'
                                   GROUP BY app_id) as bts
                                  INNER JOIN user bs ON bs.id = bts.user_id
                                  INNER JOIN club c ON c.id = bs.club_id
                                WHERE count > 1)
    ORDER BY bt.app_id DESC, bt.id ASC) bt
WHERE bt.state = 'finished'
GROUP BY bt.app_id, bt.id
ORDER BY bt.app_id DESC, bt.id DESC;
```

This however does not seem to be working with `GROUP BY bt.app_id, bt.id`

As I get something like:

```
app_id         user_id
10010          25024
10010          25022
10008          24795
10008          24784
10006          24783
```

I thought it would GROUP BY app_id but it clearly has duplicate for example `10010`

What would be the reason for this not to work?

Comment: Please do not change the question to be something completely different after you have an (accepted) answer. If you have a new/different problem, ask a new question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need to change the query for security reasons as I don't want to minimise exposure to the public. I will just rename the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would there be anything wrong with simply doing a `GROUP BY` only on `bt.bet_setting_id` ?  Change your query to the following:

```
SELECT bt.bet_setting_id, MAX(bt.id) as bet_turn_id
...
GROUP BY bt.bet_setting_id
ORDER BY bt.bet_setting_id DESC, MAX(bt.id) DESC
```

Because you were grouping by the combination of `bet_setting_id` and `id`, taking the `MAX` of the latter was meaningless, since there was only ever a single value for the `id` in each group.

Comment: I'm still using bt.id in order by so I need that column in group by

Comment: You don't need the `id` column in the `GROUP BY` clause because you can order by the aggregate `MAX(id)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your grouping is correct according to query . But rename the outer alias so that it can be clear.. as you are using subquery and both have same name BT and remove the bt_id